# java outOfMemoryError with stringbuilder

Tags: java, string, out-of-memory, heap-memory, stringbuilder

I'm getting a java outOfMemoryError when I call this method - i'm using it in a loop to parse many large files in sequence. my guess is that `result.toString()` is not getting garbage collected properly during the loop. if so, how should i fix it?

```
private String matchHelper(String buffer, String regex, String method){
    Pattern abbrev_p = Pattern.compile(regex);//norms U.S.A., B.S., PH.D, PH.D.
    Matcher abbrev_matcher = abbrev_p.matcher(buffer);
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    while (abbrev_matcher.find()){
            abbrev_matcher.appendReplacement(result, abbrevHelper(abbrev_matcher));
    }
    abbrev_matcher.appendTail(result);
    String tempResult = result.toString(); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
  return tempResult;

}
```

Comment: How big is a "large file"? It may be that you're just not allocating enough memory to the JVM.

Comment: Show error text for further investigations.

Comment: how about the pure String of 
OString Length: 2769348 ? 

Most of the String is the nexString of the photos captured

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Written this way, you'll need roughly **6** bytes of memory for every character in the file.

Each character is two bytes. You have the raw input, the substituted output (in the buffer), and you are asking for a third copy when you run out of memory.

If the file is encoded in something like ASCII or ISO-8859-1 (a single-byte character encoding), that means it will be six times larger in memory than on disk.

You could allocate more memory to the process, but a better solution might be to process the input "streamwise"—read, scan, and write the data without loading it all into memory at once.

Comment: Thumbs up. If your processing is based on line-by-line work, you could very well just use this: `BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/your/file"));` and invoke `readLine()` in a `while` loop, then do the replaces and do whatever is necessary with the changed line.

Answer (score 6):

If your files to be processed are all very large, say more than a few hundred MB, then you really should go with stream processing instead of this "loading all into memory" way, just as @erickson suggested.

Otherwise, there are a few things you could try, all to reduce memory usage as much as possible:

1. Try properly enlarge your heap size if not yet (when applicable).
2. Give `StringBuffer` an initial size same as the lenght of the given `String` `buffer`. This should reduce the unnecessary memory usage while expanding the `StringBuffer` in the process. I assume it is only replacing certain words of the original string and should be more or less the same in length.
3. If possible, maybe you could return the generated `StringBuffer` object instead. Calling its `toString()` only after you get rid of the original `String` object.

Comment: enlarging heap size woks.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon the problem with `StringBuilder.append()`. When Matcher appends sequence of characters to the Builder.

As explained in article about [OutOfMemoryError with StringBuilder/StringBuffer](http://mohammed-technical.blogspot.com/2010/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-with.html), it is a known issue that append() will double the capacity if internal buffer `chars` if the capacity is not sufficient.
Go for streams as suggested by Erickson.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other responses ... but ... simply because the exception occurs there doesn't *necessarily* mean it's the problem. You may very well be [leaking memory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/memleaks.html) elsewhere and that just happens to be the place that it's revealed. You should run a [profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/) to examine memory usage and verify exactly what objects aren't being collected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Don't buffer in memory otherwise you'll run out of it specially if you're going over 2MB on I/O.

Recommended link for fixing and appending text: http://java.ittoolbox.com/documents/appending-data-to-a-file-18786

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning a `StringBuffer` and setting it to `null` after use.