# File reading error in android. Out of memory expection

Tags: android, android-file

```
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }

protected String getStringFromFile(Context applicationContext) throws IOException 
{
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
    String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
    // Make sure you close all streams.
    fin.close();
    return ret;
}
```

I am converting the returned string into bytes. While converting into bytes it gives out of memory exception. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Contructor of class added below. 
public ReadFileManager(Context applicationContext )
 {
  file = new File(applicationContext.getFilesDir(), Constants.APP_BKP_FILE);
  
 }

Comment: Your bringing the entire file into memory which may be exceeding the amount allowed for your process.  Can you digest the file in smaller chunks do you aren't creating such a massive stringbuilder?

Comment: @Nishant i think you need `StringBuffer` and `DataInputStream` in your `convertStreamToString`. did you try that?

Comment: I dont think file is that big. I am guessing i am leaking memory somewhere..

Comment: @Amr - could you explain more?

Comment: @Nishant yes sure. but i just want to know, are you trying to read a row data from a file resides in your resource folders to show its contents on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [java outOfMemoryError with stringbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431040/java-outofmemoryerror-with-stringbuilder)

Process the file as you go rather than bringing the entire file into memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, I assume you have a raw file stored in the `resources`  under `raw` folder and want to display its contents on the screen or on a specified area of a view. if so, then you need to get the raw file in a variable of type `InputStream` as follows

```
InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.YOUR_FILE);
```

and then pass it to a method that converts the `inputStream` into a `string`, like this

```
String strFile = inputStreamToString(iFile);
```

The body of the method `inputStreamToString()` should be something like this:

```
private String inputStreamToString(InputStream iFile) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(iFile);
    String strLine = null;
    while ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
        sBuffer.append(strLine + "\n");
    }
    dataIO.close();
    iFile.close();
    return sBuffer.toString();
}
```

I am using it and it is working.